# Why an API does not recognise a HttpRequestMessage header value?

Tags: c#, curl, http-headers

I have this CURL command that I'd like to convert to C#:

```
curl -H "Api-Key: abc123" -H "Accept: application/vnd.com.some+json; version=9" https://api.someapi.io/somemethod?someParam=someparam
```

I have problem with setting the version=9 in the header. I make the request it like this:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
            {
                RequestUri = new Uri(requestURL),
                Method = HttpMethod.Get
            };

            request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/vnd.com.some+json"));
            request.Headers.Add("Api-Key", apiKey);
            request.Headers.Add("version", "9");

            var httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler();

            var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpHandler);

            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

When I call this request by curl, it works, and recognises the version value defined in the header.

Calling the API method from this c# code also works, but the API does not recognise version value defined in the header (version defines the API version). Note, my other header values (apikey, mediatype) are handled correctly by the API.

What do I miss in my code?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: In your curl command your `version` is in the `Accept` header, but in your c# code you add it as a separate header. Intentional?

Comment: As in, shouldn't it be `request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/vnd.com.some+json; version=9"));` and no `request.Headers.Add("version", "9");`

Comment: It does not work, I tried it: An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code. Format is invalid application/vnd.com.some+json; version=9

Answer (score 1):

So, finally I have found the solution:

```
request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.com.some+json;version=9");
request.Headers.Add("Api-Key", apiKey);
```

Thanks all for your help!